# MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 251 while submiting form using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I'm sending the html form using ajax to laravel controller but it showing the error that MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 251.

here is my ajax codes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Login(){

        var data = $("#login-form").serialize();
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-XSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"userAuth",
            data:data,
            success: function(response)
            {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error:function(response)
            {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

controller code

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{

    public function userAuth(Request $request)
    {
        $name = $request->username;
        die($name);
    }
}
?>
```

web.php codes

```
Route::post('/userAuth', 'LoginController@userAuth');
```

please let me know what I'm doing wrong thank and regards.

Comment: Are you uploading file from form?

Comment: Most likely has to do with CSRF. Could try moving route to api file and change Ajax request to post to the api path

Comment: no im not uploading file from form

Comment: @quickSwap I'm sending text data only

Comment: @TJWeems could you please show me how to do it

Comment: What about `php artisan route:list --path=userAuth`? Any additional middlewares on this route?

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache? `php artisan cache:clear`

Answer (score 0):

Request URL with the base URL & csrf token

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Login(){

        var data = $("#login-form").serialize();

        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });

         var getUrl = window.location;
         var baseUrl = getUrl .protocol + "//" + getUrl.host + "/" + getUrl.pathname.split('/')[1];


        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: baseUrl+"/userAuth",
            data:data,
            success: function(response)
            {
                console.log(response);
            },
            error:function(response)
            {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

in your api.php file put your route

```
Route::post('/userAuth', 'LoginController@userAuth');
```

your web.php file has a middleware for CSRF protection. You can disable it but not recommended

Comment: He already has the CSRF token in his ajax call. `'X-XSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')` Moving the route to the api.php file would also then change the url to: /api/userAuth, which you didn't mention.

Comment: It would still benefit moving to the api.php as a way to confirm that it is a CSRF issue. and I did mention changing the path in my original comment. Feel feee to post your own answer.

Comment: CSRF tokens wouldn't produce a MethodNotAllowedException

Comment: In my experience with this alarm when making Ajax requests it can. The content of the token attribute could be undefined if it’s not in the head of his document.

Comment: Null tokens would produce a separate error. The current error he is receiving is for using the wrong method. Example: POSTing to a GET route. I'm done writing comments on this post, have a good day! :)

Comment: I understand, I just resolved an issue like this recently because of CSRF with this alarm. The method in the route file is defined as POST along with the method on the Ajax is defined as POST so I’m not seeing that as the issue.